# Docker not available in GitLab CI runner container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use GitLab CI runner provided by [digitallumberjack](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallumberjack/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner/) as it provides support for using Docker commands from within the container.

GitLab CI runner script:

```
docker run --name gitlab-ci-multi-runner -d --restart=always \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/gitlab-runner:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/data \
  --env='CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.dev.abc.net/ci' --env='RUNNER_TOKEN=RijUZPnMjGeNF2JYt' \
  --env='RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=runnerA' --env='RUNNER_EXECUTOR=docker' \
  --env='RUNNER_DOCKER_IMAGE=docker:17.07.0-ce' --env='RUNNER_DOCKER_MODE=socket' \
  --link gitlab.dev.abc.net \
  digitallumberjack/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner:v9.3.0-1
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml` content:

```
image: node:6.11

types:
        - build
        - deploy

build_app:
        type: build
        script: "bash chmod +x ./configure_proxy_artifactory.sh"
        script: "bash ./configure_proxy_artifactory.sh"
```

However, when the GitLab CI build runs, i get the following error in the runner log:

```
./configure_proxy_artifactory.sh: line 13: docker: command not found
```

Seems Docker is still not configured with the above runner script. Any idea how i can fix this?

UPDATE: From within the container, here's my observation:

```
root@5489eb3ebe42:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner# ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 21 00:53 /var/run/docker.sock
root@5489eb3ebe42:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner# docker ps
bash: docker: command not found
```

Comment: Could you access the container and do a docker ps? and also have a look at if the /var/run/docker.sock is there and what permission it has

Comment: @Sergiu: Please check the `UPDATE` in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not using the official Gitlab Runner image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest but I believe it is just a matter of preference, also I would suggest that you should also pass the --privileged flag and see if that helps.

Comment: Error persists even after adding `--privileged` flag. :( Currently, i am using official Omnibus GitLab running as Docker container. However, i will be moving this to Kubernetes soon. In Kubernetes, i will be using separate containers for GitLab, Redis and Postgres. For this, i have tested [sameersbn's](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) images. I want to use those just to ensure no compatibility issue occurs. Also, i don't think even the GitLab's official runner provides Docker access, isn't it?

Comment: Well I have used that image with more or less the same config as you do /var/run/docker.sock and then I was mounting the data volume so I didn't need to pass the variables at the runtime. 

    Runner01:
      privileged: true
      image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
      stdin_open: true
      volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         - /data/runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
        - /data/gitlab/runner/data:/data
       tty: true
      labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      io.rancher.scheduler.global: 'true'

Comment: So as you can see I have been using Rancher to start my Gitlab server and runners :) I hope this helps

Comment: Also in my pipeline I was starting the DIND service as follows: services:
    - docker:dind

Comment: I was reading [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#runner-configuration) link today. I'm not sure what the `Use shell executor` tries to explain. Also from [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) link, i could understand that we should avoid using `dind`. So i finally thought of using `socket` way.

Comment: Yes there are mixed opinions about DIND and how you should use it, I remember reading a post saying that Docker isn't good and so on, but nowadays is widespread and more and more orgs are implementing it. I believe it is a matter of personal / company choices and the way it is used.

Comment: Hmmm...true. :) May i know why you're using both socket and dind for different parts of your build? When using `dind`, are you using the `overlay2` driver or the `vfs` one? Are you just using Rancher application or RancherOS as well?

Comment: Well I am using both socket and DIND cz if you try to build an image in your pipeline will fail, it will say you haven't got Docker installed. As for the driver I am using vfs :) And yes I am using Rancher on RancherOS, but isn't a must.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155277/discussion-between-technext-and-sergiu).